# Maven: Error when trying to maven test the codes

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have been trying to maven test my codes, but i keep having this in my console:

> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building SonarQube Java :: Checks 2.3-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [WARNING] The POM for
>   org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java:java-squid:jar:2.3-SNAPSHOT is
>   missing, no dependency information available [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 2.791s [INFO] Finished at: Wed May 21 16:18:34 CST
>   2014 [INFO] Final Memory: 9M/61M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project java-checks: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java:java-checks:jar:2.3-SNAPSHOT: Could
>   not find artifact
>   org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java:java-squid:jar:2.3-SNAPSHOT -> [Help
>   1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run
>   Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to
>   enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about
>   the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

My pom.xml are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
       http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">  
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>java</artifactId>
    <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>   </parent>
    <artifactId>java-checks</artifactId>
    <name>SonarQube Java :: Checks</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-deprecated</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-squid</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar.sslr</groupId>
            <artifactId>sslr-testing-harness</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
            <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Is there anyway to resolve such error?

Comment: Change that title, seriously.

Comment: Are you making your own java-squid.jar ?

Comment: user3659013, please change the title of your question. The way it is now, it will not be helpful to other users, or even just distract them. It is expected from you on this site that you try to ask good questions which will not only help you but allow others to benefit from the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this as a repository in your pom.xml. In the XML element `repositories`, add this:

```
<repository>
    <id>sonarplugins</id>
    <url>http://repository-sonarplugins.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/</url>
</repository>
```

Maven try to get `java-squid.jar` in `2.3-SNAPSHOT` version but it does not find it in your local repository, in the central Maven repository and in the repositories you indicate in your POM. The URL I give you is an URL for a public repo which contains the artifact you need. It should work, unless if there is other missing dependencies.

A few more thing: why do you use a SNAPSHOT lib? Are you really sure you want to do that?

Comment: Im getting this error now:

he project org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java:java-checks:2.3-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\L335A01\Desktop\sonar-java\sonar-runner\sonar-java\java-checks\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Malformed POM C:\Users\L335A01\Desktop\sonar-java\sonar-runner\sonar-java\java-checks\pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'repository' (position: START_TAG seen ...</dependency>\r\n    \r\n    <repository>... @22:17)  @ C:\Users\L335A01\Desktop\sonar-java\sonar-runner\sonar-java\java-checks\pom.xml, line 22, column 17 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]

Comment: @user3659013 because you do not put my code where I told you... put the code block in the "repositories" element. Just check the DTD to understand.

Comment: I get this now:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project java-checks: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Comment: @user3659013 Thanks to set the question as answered since your initial problem is resolved.
About your new problem, you should look in Google then create a new question if you didn't find anything on google.

Comment: @user3659013 When someone helps you, you can say "thank you" and mark his answer as the solution. That's the principle of this site.